# _default_root.tk.call('package', 'require', 'Togl')

Tags: python-2.7

I'm trying to run a code for molecular dynamics simulation which requires using 3D graphics.

I've installed all required packages (windows 7) but still have this error when running the code:
 File "C:/Users/San/Desktop/togl.py", line 3, in 
    from OpenGL.Tk import *
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\OpenGL\Tk__init__.py", line 121, in 
    _default_root.tk.call('package', 'require', 'Togl')
TclError: couldn't load library "C:/Python27/tcl/Togl2.0/Togl20.dll": this library or a dependent library could not be found in library path

Any help, please????
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

This is a Tcl/Tk package for which you have a tkinter wrapper. It looks like your Tcl/Tk package is missing but you have the wrapper. You will need to obtain or build a version of [togl](http://togl.sourceforge.net/) that matches your version of Python so if you have a 64 bit version of python, build a 64 bit tcl extension package. Tcl/Tk extensions should be installed into the `tcl` subdirectory of your python installation so that the Tcl package command can load them.

Comment: I'm currently using python 2.7.14 which already including Tcl/Tk .. I tried to build togl but I still have the same problem .. In addition I tried to remove Tcl/Tk  and build it but also have the same problem.. :(